# Safari web view opening when logging to FB through iOS 9

Tags: ios, safari, uiwebview, ios9

I've followed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) guide to update my application to use Facebook SDK 4.6 for iOS 9 SDK.

When I tap the login button now, a Safari view controller gets presented, whereas it should redirect to the Facebook app(App is installed on iPhone).

Is any additional handling required ? It was working fine on previous versions(v4.3.0).

Comment: I've updated SDK from beta to latest build released on 10th sept. Now instead of safariViewController, app always switched to Safari. This is weird behaviour.

Comment: check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620248/5110954
shoutout to Filip Busic

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From a product manager at Facebook in the "Facebook Developer Community" group.

[image]

And my Reply, still waiting for a response:

[image]

So it sounds like with SDK 4.6 they are forcing every login to use the Safari View Controller.

EDIT ----

And their response:
[image]

Comment: very very bad and boring !

Comment: So..That's the new way to build an app with facebook login? The only way to get the previous behavior is to downgrade my FB SDK?

Comment: Yes Rodrigo, This seems to be default behaviour. However, I'm using system credentials as priority for login.

Comment: @CanAksoy - why?

Our incentives are aligned here, and we are taking decisions based on data across our entire ecosystem to make the best possible experience for people and developers.

Hundreds of millions of people are signed into Safari, so with Safari VC they have an awesome FB Login experience - its fast and easy.

Just because you may not be signed into Safari, we suggest you don't build an app which purposefully prevents the hundreds of millions of people people who are signed into Safari from having the best possible experience.

Comment: @cheeseRoot please don't use the system credentials. You'll find that significantly more people are signed into Safari than are signed into iOS at the system level, and thus you'll be degrading people's experiences - not great for you, Facebook, or most importantly, the people who use your app.

Safari View Controller on iOS 9 offers the best user experience for the many people who are signed into Safari.

Comment: Apart from the screenshots, is there a link you can provide to the discussion within the facebook developer community?

Comment: This would be ok if the modal forced it's way to the top but it doesn't. It can sit underneath existing modals with no way of selecting it.

Comment: Most of the users will choose to use facebook app instead of browse it on safari... really a big impact for app using facebook login.

Answer (score 4):

From FacebookSDK version 4.6 and above, they are forcing every login to use the Safari View Controller on iOS 9.

There are 2 way to fix this:

1. Use the lower version of SDK
2. Enable native app login again by using this code https://github.com/tuantmdev/MTNativeFacebookLogin

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

We’ve seen hard numbers about this exact issue.  On October 8 we released the first version of the app with FBSDK 4.6  In the same update we made our login flow more prominent in the UI, so we saw a significant uptick on email signups.  However, our Facebook logins went *down* at the same time.  This effect did not occur for iOS 8 users (email and facebook logins went up together).  Here is a graph.  Red is email signups, blue is facebook for iOS 9 users only.

[Facebook vs Email signups chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OoC8.png)

tl;dr The latest update to the Facebook SDK killed our facebook conversion rates!

@ CanAksoy Is Facebook seeing the same effect internally? I agree that our interests are aligned here, what trend has moving everyone to Safari had on your conversion rates globally?

Answer (score 0):

for opening the Facebook app -

Open your plist as source code ,
And add the following code -

```
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

It is working for me in iOS 9

Answer (score -1):

I also did recieve FB login with Safari. But after setting up all config-s for iOS 9 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9), login worked with FB app again (I'm using 4.4. SDK). Anybody else with this experience?

Comment: 4.4 SDK login with FB app works, but 4.6+ SDK it doesn't

Comment: Does anybody have any feedback from users, do they like 4.6 flow, now that this is live for almost a month?