# Facebook Login - iOS 9 - Without Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios9, xcode7

It worked fine to login with logInWithReadPermissions in iOS 8, but as soon after the update to iOS 9 it keeps opening Safari or a modal UIWebView.

Does anyone have the same issue?

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email"] fromViewController:nil handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"");
}];
```

Comment: Checkout [Preparing Your Apps for iOS9](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9).

Comment: @DanielStorm, yeah I already did that. The answer below solved it for me

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Worked in iOS 8, but not in iOS 9. I too already made the changes listed in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using **20150708** solved it for me in iOS 9.

Link to SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150708.pkg

Comment: It works!. Incase you are working with Pod, it's Facebook SDK ver 4.4.0

Answer (score 39):

Seems there's no way to get the previous behavior using newests FB SDKs in iOS9+. You can use an old SDK to do that. Here's a response from the facebook to that question: [image]

Comment: I find that decision interesting.

Comment: @KevinJantzer - why? We've done extensive testing and research to make this decision. We want people to have the best experience and developers have the most people choose to use Facebook to log into apps - our incentives are aligned.

Comment: @SimonCross - I dont doubt you guys did your research. I was initially thrown off because although I was already logged in to the native FB app, I had to relogin with a safari view. But it appears the safari remembers by login later so that makes sense.

Comment: @KevinJantzer exactly. Once you have a Safari session (hundreds of millions of people already do) then you have a better and faster experience via Safari VC than you would via switching to the native FB app with those double-interstitials.

Comment: @SimonCross This had me stumped for ages, until i realised i was browsing in private mode. To be honest, i don't want to have to have a session stored in Safari when i already have one with the native FB app. It feels dirty. I also like to clear Safari cookies and sessions frequently for security. What makes the experience worse, is the big yellow message telling me i should be using the native app when i get sent to the web form in Safari. The experience is awful. I think you've made an unnecessary call.

Comment: @SimonCross Won't this drastically increase user drop off for login funnels (esp. punishing apps who only use Facebook-only login?) My biggest concern is that users won't remember their Facebook credentials to log into the Safari View Controller and will just bounce. Using fast-app-switching eliminates the need to remember email/password info. Did your testing/research show different results?

Comment: The downside to not using fast-app switching is you're challenged by Facebook Two-Factor Authentication on every single login :(

Comment: @ocwang - yes: we saw better performance in terms of conversion for using Safari View Controller over fast-app-switching to the native app.

Comment: for more detail on this decision: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/

Answer (score 15):

From now You can change loginBehavior to FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount, so FBSDKLoginManager gets Facebook logged in user from iOS Facebook Settings ;)

```
FBSDKLoginManager *fbLogin = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
fbLogin.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
```

From FBSDKLoginManager:

> **Declaration**: FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount
>   **Description**: If the account is not available to the app (either not configured by user or as determined by the SDK) this behavior falls back to FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative.
>   **Note**: If the account is not available to the app (either not configured by user or as determined by the SDK) this behavior falls back to FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative.

Comment: This is the best answer! It simply works.As far as I can see it falls back to LoginBehaviorNative if there is no Facebook account connected to the phone. And LoginBehaviorNative falls back to the popup browser if no app is installed.

Comment: Strange that Facebook don't think that this is the best default behaviour.

Comment: Of course, if every app is prompting people to log-in to the Safari View Controller, then they'll be logged in in Safari itself won't they? Which means that Facebook can more easily track a user's web browsing. I'd imagine that most people with the Facebook iOS app installed would have no reason to log in in Safari otherwise. A bit cynical, perhaps, but I can't see why else a Safari View Controller would be considered to be better.

Comment: I'm not sure what the downside to this is other than if one doesn't have their FB configured on the system level. I agree, this seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the latest SDK and also the native login behaviour on iOS 9

Edit `FBSDKServerConfiguration.m`'s function to always return true

```
- (BOOL)useNativeDialogForDialogName:(NSString *)dialogName
{
  return @YES;
}
```

Falling back to Safari still work if the Facebook app isn't installed

Comment: Unfortunately this is only working solution because _dialogFlows variable is always nil.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in both changelogs, as well:

[Facebook SDK for iOS Changelog v4.x](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x)

> (v4.6.0 - September 10, 2015) In addition, the SDK dialogs such as Login, Like, Share Dialogs automatically determine the best UI based on the device, including SFSafariViewController instead of Safari. Follow the our Preparing for iOS 9 guide.

[Facebook SDK for iOS Changelog v3.x](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-3.x)

> (v3.24.0 - September 10th 2015) In addition, the SDK dialogs such as Login, Like, Share Dialogs automatically determine the best UI based on the device, including SFSafariViewController instead of Safari. Follow the our Preparing for iOS 9 guide.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the doc here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

after adding point 2 and 3, my app switches to native facebook app for login...

Answer (score 1):

if you want a modal to open up and ask for facebook credentials seperately from Safari or Facebook app, just use the latest facebook sdk and set the login behaviour

```
FBSDKLoginManager *fbLogin = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb];
```

this will make the logout process more convenient and less confusing for users.

Answer (score 0):

Using this version with CocoaPods:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.4.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.4.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.4.0'
```

Comment: Compile errors: #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>  not found.

Answer (score 0):

In swift When your select login behavior is Web, Then open webView popUp. There is no login redirect to safari browser

```
// Try to login with permissions
    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the default login behavior as follows

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logOut];
```

**login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;**

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"gender",@"user_friends"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        // Process error
    }
    else if (result.isCancelled)
    {
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else
    {       
        // Now that we are authorized to view public profile and email, request that data get data from 'me'
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields" : @"first_name, last_name,email,name,gender,birthday"}] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
        {
        }];
    }
 }];
```

if the user does not have their facebook username & password filled out under the **Settings** app, then safari will pop up.

Answer (score -1):

SOLUTION!
iOS 9.2.1
Facebook SDK 4.10.0

1. Install Facebook SDK via Cocoapods
2. Set:

   FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
   loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;
3. In ~/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKServerConfigurationManager.m

Change:

```
NSOperatingSystemVersion iOS9Version = { .majorVersion = 9, .minorVersion = 0, .patchVersion = 0 };
BOOL useNativeFlow = ![FBSDKInternalUtility isOSRunTimeVersionAtLeast:iOS9Version];
```

To:

```
BOOL useNativeFlow = YES;
```

4. In ~/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.m

Change:

```
BOOL useNativeDialog = [serverConfiguration useNativeDialogForDialogName:FBSDKDialogConfigurationNameLogin];
```

To:

```
BOOL useNativeDialog = YES;
```

5. Find in Pods:

   BOOL useNativeDialog

& make the same changes if you want to use other features. For example: App Invite.

Now app uses native Facebook app to log in.

This solution works for me. Hope it helps.

P.S. Don't forget to make changes after upgrading FB SDK.