# Facebook login through Safari not using installed App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used Facebook SDK from Facebook developer portal and completed all the steps which were written but during login through Facebook from my app by default it uses Safari for login procedure.

Why doesn't it use installed app for this purpose?

Comment: Looks like it's by design in iOS9 [Facebook Login - iOS 9 - Without Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620002/facebook-login-ios-9-without-safari)

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
-(IBAction)CLK_ConnectWithFB:(id)sender
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
 // If the Facebook app is not installed on the device, falls back to \c FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser. This is the default behavior.
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_friends",@"user_posts"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
             NSLog(@"error is :%@",error);
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
             NSLog(@"error is :%@",error);
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 [self fetchUserInfo];
                 [login logOut];
             }
         }
     }];
}

-(void)fetchUserInfo
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id,name,link,first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown ,posts, friendlists"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is :%@",result);
                 NSLog(@"friend is :%@",[[result valueForKey:@"friends"]objectForKey:@"data"]);
                 NSString *photostring=[[[result valueForKey:@"picture"] objectForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"url"];
                 photostring = [photostring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];

                // [self Userlogin:[result valueForKey:@"email"] Username:[result valueForKey:@"name"] PhotoUrl:photostring LoginType:@"fb" Phoneno:@""];
             }
         }];          
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used Your code, but another problem arises, I have imported Facebook SDK in user/document set the path search path same reference add  framework in resource but still it says "No Sdk found" please help

Comment: remove facebook sdk  in your project then reinstall

Comment: i did same thing, remove reference of Facebook SDK and again drop sdk using binary link still having same error

Comment: You have a latest Facebook SDK?

Comment: New sdk in remove facebook side to facebook framwork so don't worry.

Comment: Add FBSDKShareKit.framework, FBSDKCoreKit.framework and FBSDKLoginKit.framework in your code

Comment: Remove Facebook Framework and put this framework*some*#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>  **
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91907/discussion-between-rohit-suvagiya-and-subhash-kumar).