# Google SignIn iOS GIDSIgnIn failed suddenly

Tags: ios, google-signin, gidsignin

I am using GIDSignIn for months and it is working fine previously. User sign in successfully either with Google App or in-app Browser.

Today, I get several reports that users are not able to login, and I confirmed the issue by my own testings.

The GIDSignIn now goes to traditional way, opening the in-app browser to prompt user to sign in (even though with Google App installed). After sign in, it stay at Google.com search engine, and not going back to App anymore.

I wonder if there is something wrong with Google side?

Comment: I also face the same issue. I was showing signin flow in webView only but from last 2 days it is opening into the browser. Now i added                 [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithBrowser = NO;                               Now it is working fine.

Comment: I work on the Sign-In team at Google. Can you give an example of a public app where this is happening, environment details (iOS version, SDK version, device model, etc.), and any other info on steps to reproduce? We will investigate asap.

Comment: Hi Steven, you may try the well known Trello app. I am using ipad ios 9.3.1. it happen on iphone 6s plus, and iphone ios 8.4 too. I tried with Google sign in sample app come with SDK too. It didnt call Google app for sign in, instead a safari browser is called. You may try my app too KLSE Screener
https://appsto.re/my/wjtwJ.i . I have to add safariservice framework to get sign in working with browser.

Comment: Hi Steven, just to update that my updated app version is approved by Apple (with safariservice framework). Hopefully you guys can solve the issue why it is not using Google app to sign in like before.

Comment: @Sujit are you able to sign in via Google App?

Comment: @neobie Yes i can. I wrote this code in ViewController and that controller is presented on rootViewController.                                                                   - (void)signIn {
    
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientID;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithBrowser = NO;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithWebView = YES;
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
}

Comment: @Sujit may i know what is your app name so that I can refer?

Comment: @neobie it is still under development. It looks like you have not handled call back of google login in UIApplication delegate method - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you guys didn't find a fix (@neobie: I tried your KLSE Screener app, and also the Trello app), I guess the answer is that it is currently impossible to use Google SignIn on iOS without passing through either the in-app Browser or Safari.

But I sure hope I'm wrong - since I'm trying to do sign-in with Google app as well.

My findings so far:

- Setting allowSignInWithWebView = false and allowsSignInWithBrowser = false doesn't seem to do anything. The webview still pops up.

  - I double-checked the URL Schemes (one containing REVERSED_CLIENT_ID, one containing Bundle ID) - that should not be the problem.
- I'm not sure what Google defines as "a capable Google app" or "suitable Google apps" in the ["GIDSignIn class documentation"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in) but I installed Chrome, Google+ and Gmail on my test device, and that doesn't help.
- That same GIDSignIn documentation says that **checkGoogleSignInAppInstalled** is deprecated - and "always calls back with NO on iOS 9 or above". I don't understand what that means, and can't find any further info on it. But it doesn't sound promising.
- Aside, I also had a lot of trouble with 'native' Facebook Login - and finally found that setting loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount there solves it - although I don't fully understand why FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative doesn't work. See [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620002/facebook-login-ios-9-without-safari) Note that for Facebook, several LSApplicationQueriesSchemes need to be set, but this should not be required for GIDSignIn?

So please, if I'm wrong, I'll be happy to stand corrected - tell me.

Comment: I dont use facebook login so i am not so sure. The google app sign in just suddenly cease to work correctly without any code changes. I am wondering if it is IOS or google app issue.