# Facebook iOS 9 SDK login redirects to mbasic.facebook.com on Safari

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, safari

I'm using the *iOS 9 Facebook SDK* to manage login. Prior to *iOS 9*, the process worked perfectly. It worked like this:

1) user taps on the `Log In Via Facebook` button on my app
2) user gets redirected to the Facebook app if the app is installed, otherwise redirected to Facebook's page on *Safari*
3) user authorizes my app's access to his/her *Facebook* credentials and redirects back to my app to complete login

However in iOS 9, according to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32621036/2926423) the default behavior is that in step 2), user will be redirected to his/her Facebook page on Safari instead. This behavior causes the following issue that's quite frustrating:

A particular user has his/her *Facebook* page defaulted to `mbasic.facebook.com`, and when the user clicks on `Log In Via Facebook` on my app, it opens up *Safari* under the `mbasic.facebook.com` URL, and it shows the user's *Facebook Home* view with activity feeds rather than the app authorization page where the user can authorize my app. In this case, the user would have to:
 **1) Log out of his/her *Facebook* account; 
2) Open my app, and click on the `Log In Via Facebook` button; 
3) *Safari* opens up facebook.com and user will need to first log in his/her Facebook account and then authorize my app**

This is A LOT to ask from the user. My question are:
1) How did the user get defaulted to the mbasic.facebook.com page instead of facebook.com? 
2) Is there anything that we can do in the *Facebook iOS 9 SDK* setting to override this redirect to `mbasic.facebook.com` and instead have it redirect to facebook.com like before?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out if the user does not have JavaScript enabled on mobile Safari, Facebook will redirect you to the mbasic.facebook.com site and prevent the user from logging in to your app via Facebook. There's probably not much we can do with the Facebook iOS SDK to override that. We'll just have to remind the user to enable JavaScript on Safari.