# Current State Of Fast App Switching In Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using iOS SDK v4.19.0. I want to use fast app switching for login. The following link explains that the default is safari view controller:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/

But documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 says adding the following to the info.plist will be enough to enable fast switching:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

In addition to adding that to info.plist, I am also using `LoginBehavior.Native` but I still cannot make fast app switching work.

Is it possible to use fast app switching for >iOS9 or is it strictly eliminated as an option in the Facebook SDK source code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Login - iOS 9 - Without Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620002/facebook-login-ios-9-without-safari)

Comment: @Vaiden It's been a long time since that question and things might have changed for the current version of the SDK, because the second link I provided claims that it should work. Fresh info on the current state would be appreciated.