# PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground opens a safari page to login, even after user is already logged in FB on device

Tags: parse-platform

I am using Parse to store data about the user as an Anonymous user. ANd then at some point I want to link the anonymous user to his FB account. So I am using "PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground" to do that. Now based on the parse documentation if the user is already logged in to FB on the device, the link should happen immediately. But what i am seeing is that a safari browser page opens up for the user to log in to FB, even if the user is already logged in in the Facebook app. I am using IOS 9. and the latest version of parse and facebook IOS SDK 4.8.  The whole point of linking is to avoid having the user to login to FB, so why is the login page showing up? Has anybody gotten the linking to work without the FB login page showing up? 
I am just using the code straight from the Parse documentation, see below:

```
 PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(PFUser.currentUser()!, withReadPermissions: nil, block: {
            (succeeded: Bool?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (succeeded != nil) {
                print("Woohoo, the user is linked with Facebook!")
            }
        })
```

thanks

-Malena

Comment: Did you get any further? I'm stuck at the same page.

Comment: No sorry Mattias. I'll let you know if I find a work around

Comment: Yeah, I settled down with the Safari-view as well, though I don't like it at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior in the FBSDK since 4.6 on iOS9. Older versions of iOS will still switch to the Facebook app, though.

Apparently, using an older version of the FBSDK is possible, but I wasn't able to get it working with Parse, unfortunately.

See this thread for more info [Safari web view opening when logging to FB through iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375916/safari-web-view-opening-when-logging-to-fb-through-ios-9)